# Cloud endpoints methods visibility

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an Android app with [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/), I have read a lot of documentation and tutorials about it, but there is still one information missing: How can I choose which backend's methods will be visible for Android client?
Let's say I have a FriendshipEndpoint, FriendshipEndpoint has this method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listFriendship", path = "listFriendship")
public CollectionResponse<Friendship> listFriendship(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit)
```

**EDIT** FriendshipEndpoint is annotated with `@Api` annotation

This method should be visible only in the backend (not by Android client).

I have tried to remove @ApiMethod anotation -> doesn't work, the method is still visible in the api explorer in my browser.
Setting access modifier to private is not a solution for me, because I want to call this method from other Endpoint.
Removing access modifier is also no solution for me, because I need this method to be visible from other packages (test package).

Is there a solution for this problem at all?

Comment: When you removed the `@ApiMethod` annotation, did you re-run `update` and `endpoints_get_client_lib` maven goals?  The annotation is what will cause the method to be excluded from the cloud API exposed via REST and the client library.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer
I didn't regenerate the cloud endpoints library, but after I rerun the project without `@ApiMethod` annotation, the method was still "visible for the world", so it could also be callable by Android client. What you are saying is in contrary with
"all public, non static, non bridge methods in a class with an `@Api` annotation are exposed in the API, whether they have an `@ApiMethod` annotation or not." [1], isn't it? My Endpoint is also annotated with `@Api` annotation.
(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apimethod_method-scoped_annotations)

Comment: You are correct, I'd forgotten the top level @Api annotation. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this scenario is not supported right now. The best solution is to move the method to a helper class and have it shared among all the endpoint classes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there some reference that confirms your answer, or does is imply from "there is no information, which explains how to handle visibility of cloud endpoints methods" ?

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations): "All public, non-static, non-bridge methods of a class annotated with @Api will be exposed in the public API." Also, I'm an engineer on Cloud Endpoints.